# Как подружить cin и cin.getline

Tags: c, ввод

Ребят, я просто сломал себе голову.

После того, как выбираешь пункт меню (1 или 2). Например нажимаешь добавить фильмы, Первый getline игнорируется, как будто в буфере остался текст и уже записался. Сразу просит ввести "режиссера", вводим например "test" и далее вводим "test2". Затем нажимаем показать все фильмы и в поле режиссер и жанр видим какие-то непонятные символы.

Но, если при запуске программы, вначале мы зайдем "показать все фильмы" а затем добавим запись, то при повторном вызове "показать все фильмы" строки заполнятся корректно. Что это вообще такое?

Также, если раскомментировать ввод рейтинга и цены(cin>>...), при добавлении фильма, то результаты весьма странные могут быть.

В чем проблема моих бед и как посоветуете это победить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
struct Film
{
    char name[50];
    char producer[50];
    char genre[30];
    float rating;
    float price;
};
int size=2;
Film *VideoArr=new Film[size];
void DefaultEntries() //Заполняем массив значениями по умолчанию.
{
        strcpy(VideoArr[0].name, "Американский пирог");
        strcpy(VideoArr[0].producer, "Пол Вайц");
        strcpy(VideoArr[0].genre, "комедия");
        VideoArr[0].rating=7.3;
        VideoArr[0].price=58.5;
        strcpy(VideoArr[1].name, "Великий Гэтсби");
        strcpy(VideoArr[1].producer, "Баз Лурман");
        strcpy(VideoArr[1].genre, "драма");
        VideoArr[1].rating=8.073;
        VideoArr[1].price=38.7;
}
void PrintArr() //Показываем все записи массива.
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<".\n";
        cout<<"\n\tНазвание фильма: "<<VideoArr[i].name<<endl;
        cout<<"\tРежиссер: "<<VideoArr[i].producer<<endl;
        cout<<"\tЖанр: "<<VideoArr[i].genre<<endl;
        cout<<"\tРейтинг: "<<VideoArr[i].rating<<"\\10"<<endl;
        cout<<"\tЦена диска: "<<VideoArr[i].price<<" грн"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    }
}
void AddArr(int &size)
{   
        ++size;
        cout<<"\n\tВведите название фильма: ";
        cin.getline(VideoArr[size-1].name, 50);
        cout<<"\tВведите режиссера: ";
        cin.getline(VideoArr[size-1].producer, 50);
        cout<<"\tВведите жанр: ";
        cin.getline(VideoArr[size-1].genre, 30);

        /*cout<<"\tВведите рейтинг: ";
        //cin>>VideoArr[size].rating;
        cout<<"\tВведите цену диска: ";
        //cin>>VideoArr[size].price;    */

}
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,""); //Подключаем русский язык.
    DefaultEntries();
    short select;
    cout<<"1 - Показать все фильмы\n2 - Добавить фильм\n3 - Выход\n";
    cin>>select;
    switch(select)
    {
        case 1:
            PrintArr();
            break;
        case 2:
            AddArr(size);
            break;
        case 3:
            return;
        default:
            cout<<"Введено недопустимое значение!\n";
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: Вы определитесь, Вам С или С++? Потому что если С, то код сильно неправильный, если С++, то его можно написать просто на порядок красивее.

Нормальным компилятором код не собирается (ни си - это логично, ни плюсовым).

рекурсия main... вроде по новому стандарту такого уже нельзя.

Comment: Нужно на Си реализовать.

У меня MVS 2010, все нормально компилируется.

Comment: @naikon на Си нет cin. Используйте gets. http://all-ht.ru/inf/prog/c/func/gets.html

Comment: в си также нет new/delete.

А студийный компилятор известен своим немного фривольным трактованием стандарта.

Comment: Вроде как, в новом стандарте есть эти операторы.

Comment: Если нужно на Си реализовать:

1) В языке Си нет <iostream>

2) В языке Си нет пространств имен namespace

3) При объявлении структур нужно указывать ключевое слово struct перед ними: struct Film *VideoArr;

4) В языке Си нет операторов new и delete, даже если они есть в новом стандарте, он вышел в 2011 и не стоит предполагать, что он в полной мере заработает в студии 2010 года. Используйте malloc и free.

5) Используйте функции gets() для чтения и printf() для вывода, т.к. там нет cin и cout потоков.

Comment: 6) Вам понадобятся заголовочные файлы: <stdio.h>(ввод\вывод), возможно <stdlib.h> (pause, malloc, free), <string.h> (strcpy)

7) Перепишите main с использованием бесконечного цикла и объявите как int main(){..... return 0;}

В общем если задача не стоит писать на С++, то переделывать придется многое. Воспользуйтесь справочником: [Шилдт. Полный справочник по C](http://www.chitay.org/c/) он подскажет, что из заголовков подключать, как использовать и что вообще есть в С89 и C99. И еще не забудьте посмотреть, как переключить MSVS на компиляцию Си проектов, а не С++ проектов. Ну или меняйте язык.

Comment: По вашей проблеме, вполне возможно там остаются символы после cin>>select;, попробуйте воспользоваться очисткой буфера flush() перед тем, как читать через getline.

Comment: @naikon,

    В чем проблема моих бед и как посоветуете это победить?

Для начала перейдите с винды в \*nix и пишите на чистом Си.

--

Для ввода смеси типов (да ведь еще и анализировать правильность введенных данных иногда надо, а в случае ошибки в формате (преобразовании) как-то восстанавливаться) 

используйте ввод из файла (с клавиатуры)  целыми строками с последующим разбором строки.

--

Это если хотите что-то научиться делать серьезно, ну а для студенческих поделок и ... (в общем, думаю, понятно).

Comment: советую переключить студию в режим компилляции Си, хранить файлы с расширением *.c (вместо *.cpp) и вообще подучить сам язык, чтоб понимать, что Вы делаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я взял на себя смелость, переписать на чистом С. Этот код не идеальный, но для сдачи в ВУЗе думаю будет предостаточно.

Переписывая код, я понял, почему плохо отрабатывал ввод. У Вас выделен массив на два элемента, а в процессе ввода Вы его не увеличивали. В результате, оно писало данные за пределы массива, а это может приводить к чему угодно (на самом то деле, к чему оно приведет, предсказать можно для каждого конкретного случая, учитывая компилятор, операционку и текую фазу Луны).

студийный компилятор может ругаться на некоторые функции и предлагать заменить их его любимыми аналогами с `_s` на конце. Это его личные тараканы и если Вам нужно будет запустить код под студией, переделывайте самостоятельно. С помощью gcc и clang код компилируется без единой ошибки на максимальном уровне паранойи (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

Также, в коде используются fgets вместо gets. gets на данный момент считается дурным тоном - он не проверяет размер вводимых данных и может организовать переполнение.

Ещё в коде есть goto. Да, некоторые начитавшись Дейкстры, начали кричать во все горло, что goto это плохо. Но проблема не в goto, а в пишущем.

Результирующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Film
{
    char name[50];
    char producer[50];
    char genre[30];
    float rating;
    float price;
};

int size;

struct Film *VideoArr;

/* Удаляем конечные переводы строк, так как fgets их может добавлять */
void strip(char * str)
{
    int len = strlen(str);
    if( str[len-1] == '\n' )
        str[len-1] = 0;
}

void DefaultEntries() /*Заполняем массив значениями по умолчанию.*/
{
    size = 2;
    VideoArr=(struct Film*)malloc( sizeof(struct Film) * size);

        strcpy(VideoArr[0].name, "Американский пирог");
        strcpy(VideoArr[0].producer, "Пол Вайц");
        strcpy(VideoArr[0].genre, "комедия");
        VideoArr[0].rating=7.3;
        VideoArr[0].price=58.5;

    strcpy(VideoArr[1].name, "Великий Гэтсби");
        strcpy(VideoArr[1].producer, "Баз Лурман");
        strcpy(VideoArr[1].genre, "драма");
        VideoArr[1].rating=8.073;
        VideoArr[1].price=38.7;
}
void PrintArr() /*Показываем все записи массива. */
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d.\n", i+1);
        printf("\n\tНазвание фильма: %s\n",VideoArr[i].name);
        printf("\tРежиссер: %s\n",VideoArr[i].producer);
        printf("\tЖанр: %s\n",VideoArr[i].genre);
        printf("\tРейтинг: %.4f\\10\n",VideoArr[i].rating);
        printf("\tЦена диска: %.2f грн\n",VideoArr[i].price);
        printf("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
void AddArr()
{   
    char buf[256];
        ++size;
    VideoArr = (struct Film*) realloc(VideoArr, sizeof(struct Film) * size);
        printf("\n\tВведите название фильма: ");
        fgets(VideoArr[size-1].name, 50, stdin);
    strip(VideoArr[size-1].name);
        printf("\tВведите режиссера: ");
        fgets(VideoArr[size-1].producer, 50, stdin);
    strip(VideoArr[size-1].producer);
        printf("\tВведите жанр: ");
        fgets(VideoArr[size-1].genre, 30, stdin);
    strip(VideoArr[size-1].genre);

        printf("\tВведите рейтинг: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
        VideoArr[size].rating = atof(buf);
        printf("\tВведите цену диска: ");
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    VideoArr[size].price = atof(buf);

}
int main()
{
    DefaultEntries();
    while (1) {
        int select;
        char cselect[256];
        puts("1 - Показать все фильмы");
        puts("2 - Добавить фильм");
        puts("3 - Выход");
        fgets(cselect, sizeof(cselect), stdin);
        select = atoi(cselect);
        switch(select)
        {
        case 1:
            PrintArr();
            break;
        case 2:
            AddArr();
            break;
        case 3:
            goto exit;
            /*что бы там не говорили обиженные Java программисты,
             у которых goto ключевое слово, но использовать его нельзя, 
             в C goto очень нужный инструмент.*/
        default:
            printf("Введено недопустимое значение! - [%d]", select);
        }
    }
exit:
    free(VideoArr);
    return 0;
}
```